# JMeter - How can I use multiple conditions in IF Controller?

Tags: if-statement, jmeter

Here is my code:

In If Controller -> Condition (Default Javascript) I am providing following
"${responsecode}" == "404" || "${responsecode}" == "500"  && "${responseMessage}" == "Not Found"
[image: image also added in fact I want to send email only in such conditions]

Comment: What is the problem with current code? Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, assuming your current condition **SMTP Sampler** will be executed:

- If `${responsecode}` variable is `404`

  **OR**
- If `${responsecode}` variable is `500` **AND** `${responseMessage}` variable is `Not Found`

---

I doubt that you will get `Not Found` message given [Response Code 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500), most likely you will get an `Internal Server Error` there so maybe you should amend your condition to look like:

```
"${responsecode}" == "500" || ("${responsecode}" == "404" && "${responseMessage}" == "Not Found")
```

In case when If Controller doesn't behave as expected first of all check *jmeter.log* file for any JavaScript-related errors, it will give you some clue regarding what's wrong with your setup. You can also use [__javaScript() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) and [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination to visualize the result of your If Controller condition:

[image: JMeter Javascript Debug]

See [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) article for more details on conditionally running samplers via If Controller.