# Jmeter: unable to use multiple conditional statements in If Controller

Tags: if-statement, jmeter

### ANSWER TO THE QUESTION

Please, dear reader, if you wish, you can proceed further and read through the question. But at the most top I'm willing to provide Dmitri's answer, so that others won't waste time playing around with Jmeter If Controller.

> If you wish to use multiple condition statement in If Controller,
>   specifically if you want to check that variables equal some strings,
>   DON'T USE ${__javaScript()} FUNTION!!! Dmitri suggested to use instead
>   ${__groovy()} function, which worked in my situation. Correct syntax
>   below. Pay attention to opening parenthesis, comma location and closing curly brackets:
>
> ${__groovy((vars.get('yourVariable').equals('someString') &&
>   vars.get('yourAnotherVariable').equals('someOtherString')),)}

### Addition

If you want to save your time while trying to make If Controller working with multiple conditions, always uncheck **Interpret Condition as Variable Expression** checkbox. Otherwise you will have to stuck with those __javaScript, __groovy or other functions, as there is no way to understand how the hell they suppose to work and why they don't resolve to true or false (log file is always clean at this situation). This is how you do without help of those "functions". Please see my example below

```
${yourVariable} != 'not_found' && ${youAnotherVariable_matchNr} == 1
```

That's it, no need to use any functions.

[image]

---

### INITIAL QUESTION

In **Jmeter v4.0 r 1823414** I can use **If Controller** only with single statement, but not with multiple. Example of using multiple statements I have taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867125/jmeter-how-can-i-use-multiple-conditions-in-if-controller) and it was suggested to use

> ${__javaScript("${responsecode}"=="404")} &&
>   ${__javaScript("${responseMessage}" == "Not Found")}

I have also checked [blazemeter tutorial page](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie), but it says nothing about multiple conditional statements inside **If Controller**.

Example of my Test Plan is below

[image]

In my Debug Sampler I can see following

[image]

At some place in the Test Plan I put **IF Controller** to check that both variables are equal to `not_found`...

```
${__javaScript(vars.get('manual_bug')=='not_found')} && ${__javaScript(vars.get('integration_bug')=='not_found')}
```

...so all the subsequent actions are executed. However, this **IF Controller** either never gets executed or always return FALSE. Not sure what's happening with it.

Before blaming me :-) that I didn't do enough research and rushed to ask a question on SO, I will provide below samples of what I've already tried and that didn't help:

- With double quotes around variables

  ${__javaScript(vars.get("manual_bug")=="not_found")} && ${__javaScript(vars.get("integration_bug")=="not_found")}
- With additional space between equal sign

${__javaScript(vars.get('manual_bug') == 'not_found')} && 
${__javaScript(vars.get('integration_bug') == 'not_found')}

- Avoid using vars.get

${__javaScript(${manual_bug} == 'not_found')} && ${__javaScript(${integration_bug} == 'not_found')}

- Using double quotes without vars.get

  ${__javaScript(${manual_bug} == "not_found")} && ${__javaScript(${integration_bug} == "not_found")}

My log file looks completely fine, no errors

[image]

[image]

Please advise if someone was able to execute multiple conditional statements in the Jmeter tool? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the link you're referencing the 2 clauses are in a **single** [__javaScript() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) and you have 2 different functions so JMeter doesn't know what does your `&&` means especially given  `Interpret Condition as Variable Expression?` default mode of the If Controller.

Also if you open [If Controller GUI](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) you will see the following warning:

> For performance it is advised to check "Interpret Condition as Variable Expression"
>       and use __jexl3 or __groovy evaluating to true or false or a variable that contains true or false.
>       ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} can be used to test if last sampler was successful

Therefore I would recommend reconsidering your approach and use [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), the relevant syntax would be:

```
${__groovy((vars.get('responseCode').equals('404') && vars.get('responseMessage').equals('Not Found')),)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter If Controller Multiple Clauses]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. In every example that I provided I use 2 __javascript() functions each of which should return either true or false. Isn't this the default behavior Jmeter should understand? No?

Comment: You are referring [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43867731/2897748) which is upvoted and accepted and surprisingly it has multiple conditions [wrapped into a single function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z8SV.png). No? I would expect a little bit higher level of attention to details from a person who considers himself a form of QA engineer. No?

Comment: Sorry I'm not in the IT field at all, so may be didn't notice some details.

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax (with double quotes) works too, however it also requires that you uncheck the 'Interpret Condition as Variable Expression' setting.

```
"${yourVariable}" != "not_found" && "${youAnotherVariable_matchNr}" == "1"
```